# Azure Function Node app NPM dependencies not resolving

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, azure-functions

I deployed a Node (TypeScript) Azure Function app via VSCode Azure Function extension. In the deployment output I am seeing this log line:

```
Started postDeployTask "npm install (functions)".
```

However, I am not seeing any node_modules folder in the Kudu console under wwwroot folder or any other folder for the Azure Function.

Also I cannot import my package.json through the Kudu console since the app is in read only mode.

Does it just take time for the postDeployTask for npm insall to complete? It has been almost 45 minutes since the deployment and still no node_modules folder.

Answer (score 0):

We had did a repro by creating a function app of typescript & tried deploying the function app from vs code to Azure using `deploy to Azure function app` option in Visual studio code. we can see those node modules under /site/wwwroot post the deployment got succeeded in the vscode.

Here is the Output screenshot for reference.

[image]

Note : If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have found the issue, looks like since I nested my index.ts and other ancillary ts files under a nested "src" folder it no longer conformed to a flat folder structure mandated by Azure Function to operate. I just moved all the ts and js files under the function root and it worked.